# How to pass a reference of template reference into class method?

Tags: c++, class, methods, data-structures, reference

I have been working on this problem for a few days and can not find a solution to my problem online. The problem given to me was to create an insert and erase method for a vector class. The method headers were given to me as `iterator insert(iterator pos, const Object& x);` and `iterator erase(iterator pos);`. When I made a vector class everything compiled without errors other than never being used. the code is as follows.

```
template<typename iterator, typename Object> class Vector
{
public:
    iterator insert(iterator pos, const Object& x)
    {
        element[pos] = x;
    }
    iterator erase(iterator pos)
    {
        element[pos] = '\0';
    }
private:
    iterator pos;
    Object element;
};
```

The main function looks like this:

```
int main()
{
    Vector<int, class Object> myVec;
    int i = 9;
    myVec.insert(0,i);
}
```

After I finished that the only error occors on the line `Object element` line. With the error message "Field has incomplete type 'Object'". I apologize if this is very simple to fix but I am new to iterators and vectors so to have to create the methods myself is confusing. All help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `Vector<int, class Object>` needs to be `Vector<int, int>`. There are more problems in your code. Please take the time to learn the basics of the language from [a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Your `insert` function doesn't insert, it replaces. Your `erase` function doesn't erase either. It will not work for every type of object. I suspect you are not going to get credited for this.

Comment: There are multiple errors. Apart from the ones already noted in the comments you would have to declare an array of type Object. The insert() function you have written takes an iterator as the first parameter, but you are giving the value of 0.